# How to Call upon a class (inside of another class)

Tags: java

so I would like to run the class "WASD" which I have in my code:

```
public class MoveWASD extends JFrame
{
boolean Repeat = true;
int Location[] = {40, 40};
public static void main (String args[])
{
    new MoveWASD();
}

public MoveWASD() 
{
    super("Use-WASD-to-Move");
    setSize(800, 450);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    while(Repeat)
    {
```

-->      WASD();
        }

```
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 450);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(Location[0], Location[1], 20, 20);
}

public class WASD implements KeyListener
{





    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getKeyChar() == 'w')
        {
            Location[1]--;
        }
        else if(event.getKeyChar() == 'd')
        {
            Location[0]++;
        }
        else if(event.getKeyChar() == 's')
        {
            Location[1]++;
        }
        else if (event.getKeyChar() == 'a')
        {
        Location[0]--;
        }
        else
        {
        Location[0] = Location[0];
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}

}
```

The arrow points to syntax error in my code, apparently when I type in WASD(); it want there to be a method called WASD, what would I need to do for it to look for the CLASS WASD?

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions. It should be `repeat` and `location` (not capitalized).

Comment: you can't call a class , you can create a new object, 
or you can call a static method inside the class.
exactly what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> WASD();

this is a call to a function.if you want to call the class WASD from MOVEASD then use the new operator..

> new WASD();

Comment: Thanks, but how would I do that?

Comment: just replace wasd() by new WASd() ??